# OPC UA Milo - Collection of Monitored Items in Callback onDataChangeNotification

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I am testing some things with the SubscriptionExample of the Eclipse Milo OPC-UA project (https://github.com/eclipse/milo) and found a behavior which I am not sure it is intended. I created two MonitoredItemCreateRequests for each of two different nodes on the Milo test server (opc.tcp://milo.digitalpetri.com:62541/milo/) and passed them to the createMonitoredItems() method of the subscription. Status code for both items is good. Since I want to get all collected values for both monitored items at once I added a NotificationListener to the subscription.

```
NodeId dynNodeId = NodeId.parse("ns=2;s=Dynamic/RandomInt32");
NodeId statNodeId = NodeId.parse("ns=2;s=Dynamic/RandomDouble");
```

Here is the callback method to receive the data values:

```
@Override
public void onDataChangeNotification(UaSubscription subscription, List<UaMonitoredItem> monitoredItems, List<DataValue> dataValues, DateTime publishTime) {
        Iterator<UaMonitoredItem> itemIterator = monitoredItems.iterator();
        Iterator<DataValue> dataValueIterator = dataValues.iterator();

        while(itemIterator.hasNext() && dataValueIterator.hasNext()) {
            logger.info("subscription value received: item={}, value={}",
                    itemIterator.next().getReadValueId().getNodeId(), dataValueIterator.next().getValue());
        }
    }
```

I expected that the list of monitoredItems holds the items with the OPC-UA node ID in the order corresponding to the list of dataValues. By debugging one can see that the size of both collections are equal -- that is fine. But all the monitored items in the callback have the same node ID? The node ID for the logged Double values should have the ID ns=2;s=Dynamic/RandomDouble.

```
15:32:01.221 [milo-shared-thread-pool-0] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=0.19167566173987927}
15:32:01.221 [milo-shared-thread-pool-0] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=0.17914743791503218}
15:32:01.221 [milo-shared-thread-pool-0] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=-1911450762}
15:32:01.221 [milo-shared-thread-pool-0] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=-238565139}
15:32:02.172 [milo-shared-thread-pool-1] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=0.004420353528696297}
15:32:02.173 [milo-shared-thread-pool-1] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=1391780361}
15:32:03.171 [milo-shared-thread-pool-2] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=0.5815483661983246}
15:32:03.172 [milo-shared-thread-pool-2] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=560950904}
15:32:04.245 [milo-shared-thread-pool-2] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=0.18123040450226635}
15:32:04.246 [milo-shared-thread-pool-2] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=521198031}
15:32:05.258 [milo-shared-thread-pool-2] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=0.42193483414925215}
15:32:05.258 [milo-shared-thread-pool-2] INFO  o.e.m.e.client.SubscriptionExample - subscription value received: item=NodeId{ns=2, id=Dynamic/RandomInt32}, value=Variant{value=680732464}
```

I am aware of the possibility of using a individual callback for each node, but I want to handle them all at once.

Is this behavior intended or could it be a bug in the server implementation?

Edit:

During debugging I found that the collection of the monitoredItems in the callback holds x times the same object (same memory address) but the x dataValues differ.

Same behavior if I try it with the local OPC server from the milo example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably used the same `clientHandle` value in both of your items `MonitoringParameters` when you created them.

If not can you post your entire example code?

Comment: Perfect! I forgot to create a separate `clientHandle` -- my fault. Thanks Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting values for all my subscribed node rather getting only the last one passed in the newArrayList. getting error for class cast exception when trying to pass onItemCreated in
List items = subscription.createMonitoredItems(
TimestampsToReturn.Both,
newArrayList(powerRequest,pressureRequest,speedRequest),
onItemCreated
).get();

Here is my complete code:

private void getUaSubscription(OpcUaClient client) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

```
    NodeId powerNodeIdGuid = NodeId.parse("ns=2;g=14e74bd5-d38f-4f78-855f-160562262a36");
    NodeId pressureNodeIdGuid = NodeId.parse("ns=2;g=14447164-47d3-44df-920d-2e22650f3cea");
    NodeId windspeedNodeIdGuid = NodeId.parse("ns=2;g=0e1c766a-0c72-4d40-aa46-d181e5b08de1");

    UaSubscription subscription = client.getSubscriptionManager().createSubscription(1000.0).get();

    // subscribe to the Value attribute of the Power Node of R80711 device

    ReadValueId readPowerValueId = new ReadValueId(
            powerNodeIdGuid,
            AttributeId.Value.uid(), null, QualifiedName.NULL_VALUE
    );
    ReadValueId readPressureValueId = new ReadValueId(
            pressureNodeIdGuid,
            AttributeId.Value.uid(), null, QualifiedName.NULL_VALUE
    );
    ReadValueId readSpeedValueId = new ReadValueId(
            windspeedNodeIdGuid,
            AttributeId.Value.uid(), null, QualifiedName.NULL_VALUE
    );
   // UInteger clientHandle = subscription.nextClientHandle();
    UInteger clientHandle = uint(clientHandles.getAndIncrement());
    MonitoringParameters parameters = new MonitoringParameters(
            clientHandle,
            1000.0,     // sampling interval
            null,       // filter, null means use default
            uint(10),   // queue size
            true        // discard oldest
    );
    MonitoredItemCreateRequest powerRequest = new MonitoredItemCreateRequest(
            readPowerValueId,
            MonitoringMode.Reporting,
            parameters
    );
    MonitoredItemCreateRequest pressureRequest = new MonitoredItemCreateRequest(
            readPressureValueId,
            MonitoringMode.Reporting,
            parameters
    );
    MonitoredItemCreateRequest speedRequest = new MonitoredItemCreateRequest(
            readSpeedValueId,
            MonitoringMode.Reporting,
            parameters
    );

   
    BiConsumer<UaMonitoredItem, Integer> onItemCreated =
            (item, id) -> item.setEventConsumer(this::onSubscriptionValue);



    List<UaMonitoredItem> items = subscription.createMonitoredItems(
            TimestampsToReturn.Both, //Return both the SourceTimestamp and ServerTimestamp
            newArrayList(powerRequest,pressureRequest,speedRequest),
             onItemCreated
    ).get();


    for (UaMonitoredItem item : items) {
        if (item.getStatusCode().isGood()) {
            logger.info("item created for nodeId={}", item.getReadValueId().getNodeId());


        } else {
            logger.warn(
                    "failed to create item for nodeId={} (status={})",
                    item.getReadValueId().getNodeId(), item.getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    // let the example run for 5 seconds then terminate
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    future.complete(client);


}
```

private void onSubscriptionValue(UaMonitoredItem uaMonitoredItem, DataValue dataValue) {
logger.info(
"subscription value received: item={}, value={}, time={}",
uaMonitoredItem.getReadValueId().getNodeId(), dataValue.getValue(), dataValue.getServerTime().getJavaDate());
}
}